# How to replace empty string with value that is not empty for the same PolicyNumber

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The goal is to replace empty value in `ClaimType` column with value that is not empty for each `CoverageType` and `PolicyNumber`

[image]

For some reason SELECT statement I wrote doesn't give me desirable result. 
In my WHERE clause I specified:

```
 where  
             PolicyNumber = c.PolicyNumber 
            and CoverageType = c.CoverageType
```

But why for `PolicyNumber` 00002 I have 'Occurance' for CPL `CoverageType`?

I expected to see `Occurrence-Pollution` instead:

[image]

What am I missing here?

```
declare @ClaimType table (PolicyNumber varchar(50), QuoteID int,  CoverageType varchar(50), ClaimType varchar(100))

insert into @ClaimType values   ('00001',1, 'CGL', ' '),
                                ('00001',2, 'CGL', 'Occurrence'),
                                ('00002',1, 'CPL', ' '),
                                ('00002',2, 'CPL', 'Occurrence-Pollution')

select PolicyNumber,
        QuoteID,
        CoverageType,
        ClaimType,
        case when ClaimType = ' ' then (
                                        select top 1 ClaimType  
                                        from @ClaimType c 
                                        where   
                                                 PolicyNumber = c.PolicyNumber 
                                                and CoverageType = c.CoverageType 
                                        order by QuoteID desc
                                        ) 
                                        else ClaimType End as ClaimType1
from @ClaimType
go
```

Comment: what version of sql server

Comment: dang @SeanLange you were faster than my answer

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: @scsimon but what I stated doesn't quite get it .

Comment: What are you expecting as the output?

Comment: I think it did @SeanLange judging by the arrow they drew (well, and the edit now)

Comment: Hi Oleg...I'm sure that this is what you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63c07/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlate the subquery or you can use `LEAD`.

```
select PolicyNumber,
        QuoteID,
        CoverageType,
        ClaimType,
        case when ClaimType = ' ' then (
                                        select top 1 ClaimType  
                                        from @ClaimType c 
                                        where   
                                                 x.PolicyNumber = c.PolicyNumber 
                                                and x.CoverageType = c.CoverageType 
                                        order by QuoteID desc
                                        ) 
                                        else ClaimType End as ClaimType1
from @ClaimType x


select
    PolicyNumber
    ,QuoteID
    ,CoverageType
    ,ClaimType
    ,ClaimType1 = case when ClaimType = '' or ClaimType is null then lead(ClaimType) over (partition by PolicyNumber, CoverageType order by QuoteID) else ClaimType end
from @ClaimType
```

If there are multiple blanks or the pattern breaks where the `QuoteID = 2` isn't the one that is populated, I'd as a where clause to the sub query. Notice the extra row I added and the where clause addition.

```
declare @ClaimType table (PolicyNumber varchar(50), QuoteID int,  CoverageType varchar(50), ClaimType varchar(100))

insert into @ClaimType values   ('00001',1, 'CGL', ' '),
                                ('00001',2, 'CGL', 'Occurrence'),
                                ('00002',1, 'CPL', ' '),
                                ('00002',2, 'CPL', 'Occurrence-Pollution'),
                                ('00002',3, 'CPL', '')  --added this row

select PolicyNumber,
        QuoteID,
        CoverageType,
        ClaimType,
        case when ClaimType = ' ' then (
                                        select top 1 ClaimType  
                                        from @ClaimType c 
                                        where   
                                                 x.PolicyNumber = c.PolicyNumber 
                                                and x.CoverageType = c.CoverageType 
                                                and c.ClaimType != '' --added this clause
                                        order by QuoteID desc
                                        ) 
                                        else ClaimType End as ClaimType1
from @ClaimType x
```

Comment: Thanks @scsimon. So basically the alliance for table ClaimType I missed is what caused incorrect output?

Comment: the alias yes so that you could fully correlate your sub-query. But, as i noted, you'll need the additional where clause if there is more than 1 blank row.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select ct.*,
       coalesce(nullif(ltrim(ClaimType), ''),
                max(ClaimType) over (partition by PolicyNumber, CoverageType)
               ) as ClaimType_2
from @ClaimType ct;
```

Comment: I think this may be what they are after. But trim is not a t-sql function. It also isn't needed here because a single space string is the same thing as an empty string in sql server. :)

Comment: Thank you @Gordon. Your answer is simple and great. I was looking for into understanding what am I doing wrong in my SELECT clause.

Comment: @Oleg . . . And you chose a more complicated, less performant answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not reverencing back to the main table so

```
where PolicyNumber = c.PolicyNumber 
and   CoverageType = c.CoverageType
```

is always true.

You need to alias back to the main table.

```
select PolicyNumber,
        QuoteID,
        CoverageType,
        ClaimType,
        case when ClaimType = ' ' then ( select top 1 ClaimType  
                                         from @ClaimType c 
                                         where m.PolicyNumber = c.PolicyNumber 
                                           and m.CoverageType = c.CoverageType 
                                         order by QuoteID desc
                                        ) 
                                   else ClaimType End as ClaimType1
from @ClaimType m
go
```